why does a printer drop an ipp connection over IEEE 802.11?
Please see the attached screenshot.  Note unable to locate npi....   When the HP printer is rebooted at the printer, using the identical configuration, the printer works.  After some time (the end-user has not discovered how long -- longer than a few minutes, but shorter than a few hours, no reboot of either the computer nor the printer), CUPS can no longer "find" the printer.  What causes this?  Note that hplip is not being used as the printer application, installed from apt-get install, because that application has unsatisfied needs under 24.04 that I cannot find after extensive searching on the web and this Ask Ubuntu.  All that I used was the web browser CUPS configuration/administration interface.  Does a printer "reconfigure" the connection with a computer such that it does not "work"?  Could the end-user "router" (not under control of the end-user, but only from the ISP that is the landline telephone provider (Frontier)) periodically reconfigure/drop the connection and then "rediscovering" the connection when the printer is rebooted?  Any assistance would be appreciated.


IEEE 802.11 = Wireless. Wireless connections dropping over time, or encountering interference, is not unheard of. A dhcp lease expiring while the connection is dropped is also not unheard of. A consumer-grade router "forgetting" leases or connections due to memory overflow is also a moderately common occurrence. Many ordinary possibilities that don't involve "reconfiguring."
